# How to use existing js libraries in sencha touch (modernizr)

Tags: extjs, menu, touch, libraries, modernizr

I found a cool Menu i want to include in my app ( http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/...vel-push-menu/ ).

All the files are in the right folders.

At first I tried to include the source to the index.html, but it didn't work. 
Then it tried to do it via a HTML Panel:

HTMLPanel.js

```
Ext.define('HTMLPanel', {    extend: 'Ext.Panel',


// We are using Ext.Ajax, so we should require it
requires: ['Ext.Ajax'],


config: {
    listeners: {
        activate: 'onActivate'
    },


    // Create a new configuration called `url` so we can specify the URL
    url: null
},


onActivate: function(me, container) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        // we should use the getter for our new `url` config
        url: this.getUrl(),
        method: "GET",
        success: function(response, request) {
            // We should use the setter for the HTML config for this
            me.setHtml(response.responseText);
        },
        failure: function(response, request) {
            me.setHtml("failed -- response: " + response.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

});
app.js

```
var HTMLPanel = Ext.create('HTMLPanel', {            // this is now `scrollable`, not `scroll`
        //scroll: 'vertical',
        scrollable: 'vertical',


        url: 'menu.html'
    });

    // Add the new HTMLPanel into the viewport so it is visible
    Ext.Viewport.add(HTMLPanel);
```

That solution only loads the HTML Code, but does not start the script to load the menu.

I included the need files in my index.html as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/icons.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/mlpushmenu.js"></script>
```

Any hint in the right direction would be appreciated !!

I alread tried the  solution. It works, but it's hard to do proper layout with the rest of the content this way!!

best regards, manu

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add static JS resources to your app.json file.